# Application Configs for PhoneGap App

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am quite new to PhoneGap as well as Android development. I am building an app which acts as an client to some service. I want to store some parameters which I can use throughout the application via JavaScript. Basically, my client will interact with one of many server, and I want to give URL to that server at the time of (or before) building the app apk so that all requests are sent to that particular server via that build. How do I do it with PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized there is a simple and silly solution to this. I am creating some JS variables which will act as my config param and putting it inside a `config.js` file and I am including this file in my all pages.